# setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) not working when element is not the last in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm updating my interface programmatically in order to show an ImageView inside my main menu. It works correctly when the ImageView is the last inside his parent (a LinearLayout). But it doesn't work when it is the first item in Layout or is between some others elements.

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="right"
tools:context=".Actualidad" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/main_bg" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/iSV_Botones_drc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drc_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_main_actualidad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxWidth="9dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btnmenuiconactualidad" />


         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_main_discos_giras"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/menu_items_margin_top"
            android:src="@drawable/btnmenuicondiscos"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_main_espectaculos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/menu_items_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/btnmenuiconeventos" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is the code where I set visible the ImageView (iv_main_discos_giras):

```
private Handler mResultHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mDiscosGiras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Item visible!!");
    }
};
```

Log is being shown correctly, and mDiscosGiras has been already initialized:

```
@InjectView(R.id.iv_main_discos_giras) ImageView mDiscosGiras; here
```

Comment: This behaviour is weird. My hunch is that the framework is optimising out the change of visibility because of other conditions preventing the View being displayed. Try adding "android:layout_weight=0" to iv_main_discos_giras, but I cannot guarantee. Also, I am not familiar with injection, but are you sure you have the right ImageView instance in mDiscoGiras?

Comment: Yes!! You've got it. Setting layout_weight='0' make it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a hack that is working very well.

I simply make invisible all items below that item for a moment. Then I set visibles all items, from top to bottom.

NOTE: This works also with `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in LinearLayout, with a nice animation.

```
private Handler mResultHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mEspectaculos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mDiscosGiras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
        mEspectaculos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Ponemos el tema visible");
    }
};
```